# Select first element of a type on page even when elements are nested at different levels

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am practicing with CSS selectors.  I know I could do this easily by specifying a `class` or an `id`, but for the purpose of the exercise: I'm curious if the following is possible without using those two CSS tools:

Imagine that I have have a whole bunch of `p` elements, and each `p` element is nested an unknown number of times in unknown block type elements.  Ultimately I want to grab the very first `p` element that appears on the page and color its text red.  How would I do that?

My following attempt does not work because the `:first-of-type` selector just grabs the first `p` element of its parent, so that doesn't help me here because each `p` element has different parents, so all the `p` elements on the page get selected.

I also attempted to wrap everything inside a `div` and then just grab the first `p` element inside that global `div`, but that didn't work either:

```
div:first-of-type p:first-of-type{
  color: red;  
}
```

```css
p:first-of-type{
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <p> p element at one nesting</p>
</div>

<p> p element not nested</p>

<h1>
  <p> p element at one nesting (oddly nested inside h1 tag)</p>
</h1>

<div>
  <div> 
    <p> p element at two nestings</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that if you have HTML with a random location for the first p, you cannot currently do what you are trying to do w/o Javascript (but I hope someone proves me wrong)

Comment: you must know the markup to achieve what you want

Comment: for the simple reason that CSS does not care about the DOM and has no control over it. It only adjust how to display it.

Comment: I find this amusing, OP tags the answer as CSS, and refers that is practicing CSS selectors, but hey there is a (obviosly easy) jQuery answer.  So lets go with that?

Comment: @dippas, the accepted answer is the one I chose because it explained that there is not a css answer without `id` or `class` for this scenario.  It was just a bonus that he provided a jQuery answer. If you (or anyone) provides a css answer then I will change the accepted answer.

Comment: @happymacarts what did you do with the accepted answer? I did not mark yours as the accepted answer and now the one I marked as accepted is gone.

Comment: @Neil. I didn't do anything with it. maybe the original supplier deleted it.

Comment: @dippas. I commented in response to The One and Only Chemistry Blob's comment that it really can't be done and then provided a jquery solution. I also stated in my answer that in plain ol css it can't be done. (at least not easily and that I wanted to try)

Comment: @happymacarts my apologies.  For some reason I thought you had provided a jQuery answer, but I don't think you did.  Instead I think you just referenced that one would use jQuery.

Comment: @neil no biggie, I did below, but I also said its not possible regular try it this way...

Comment: @happymacarts You sure did!  So sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is an unspecified depth and no class assignments it becomes very difficult to target this without traversing the DOM
Using Just plain-ol-vanilla css I don't see a way to do this but using a tiny jQuery you can achieve it

```js
var ps = $('p');

console.log(ps[0])
$(ps[0]).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  <p> p element at one nesting</p>
</div>

<p> p element not nested</p>

<h1>
  <p> p element at one nesting (oddly nested inside h1 tag)</p>
</h1>

<div>
  <div> 
    <p> p element at two nestings</p>
  </div>
</div>
```